# Remove HTML tags in textaera (Basic CMS)

Tags: php, html

I am very new to PHP and started making a light weight CMS. I have stored all the body content in the database and the CMS calls it from the database and displays it in a text area to be edited. However I was wondering is there a way to make it display the text without HTML tags. I have tried the `strip_tag` function however when I hit save on my cms it saves without the html tags! how will I go about making it display the data from the database without HTML tags but when I save it, it will save with the HTML tags! Sorry if this question is not clear but it is quite difficult to explain. Here is my code so far working fine:

```
<?php include_once "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
<?php include_once "includes/connect.php";?>
<?php include_once "includes/cms_page_security.php";?>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE id = '5'";   
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
    $num= mysql_numrows($result);mysql_close();
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    $pg_content = $row['1'];
if (isset($_POST['saveChanges'])){
    $pgcontent = $_POST['edit'];
    $sql_query = ("UPDATE content SET cage_content= '$pgcontent' WHERE cage_content= '$pg_content'");
    mysql_query($sql_query,$connect);
    header('location: admin_cms_staff.php');
    $feedback = "Updated successfully";
    }
?>
<div id="cms_container"><br>
    <h1>Staff Page<img src="images/three_column_grid_line.png" alt="line"></h1>
      <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
         <textarea id="content" name="edit"><?php echo $pg_content; ?></textarea>
         <input type="submit" class="submit_edit" value="Save" name="saveChanges" onClick="alertFunction()">
     </form>
    <p class="logout_btn"><a href="admin_cms.php">Back</a></p>
     <?php if(isset($_POST['saveChanges'])){
        echo $feedback;}?>
    </div><!--cms_container-->
<script>
function alertFunction()
{
var r=confirm("Do you want to save the changes you made to the page?");
if (r==true)
  {
  }
else
  {
    return;
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you really wish to strip the tags or just make them harmless? Using `htmlspecialchars` ?

Comment: I think what you want is characters escape. encode/decode see http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/escape/

Comment: Tried like this? $pgcontent = strip_tags($_POST['edit']);

Comment: I got the idea form wordpress would like to expand the cms if future to be able to switch between normal view(without HTML) and a view with HTML tags. But for now i just want the HTML to display without HTML tags. The people who will use it is only going to edit basic <p> tags and they dont want to see any HTML code

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future. You also have SQL injection vulnerabilities. I would kindly suggest you to learn the security basics a PHP programmer should know.

Comment: Thank you will look into it i am aware of it was just so use to doing it the "old" way!

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
$pgcontent = $_POST['edit'];
```

to:

```
$pgcontent = strip_tags($_POST['edit']);
```

And also change this:

```
<textarea id="content" name="edit"><?php echo $pg_content; ?></textarea>
```

to:

```
<textarea id="content" name="edit"><?php echo strip_tags($pg_content); ?></textarea>
```